# text - input box - search button stay on a same line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

bootply (http://bootply.com/99121#)

I needs " text - inputbox - search button " placed in-a-row inline, but it shows vertical and strange view.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change this HTML :

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <input name="stx" class="form-control" required="" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" itemname="search">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">search</button>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <input name="stx" class="form-control" required="" type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" itemname="search">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">search</button>
```

[**DEMO**](http://bootply.com/99122)

Comment: thanks. I changed. button on btn-group make some trobles http://bootply.com/99121

Comment: @OpenCode what is the problem ?

Comment: text - input box - button was different row. now all in the same line. bootply code was fixed and now good.